# What is the best way to organize Hotfixes

Tags: branching, gitflow, devops

I work at a rather small company, around 10 devs and we are facing a lot of problems with merges and so on, I figured it could be because of the amount Hotfixes we are merging into master daily.

So I was thinking about **one** release branch per day, where it would be on origin and whenever a dev must do a hotfix, they would use this one branch and at the end of the day, I as the manager, would then finish the hotfix.

What is the best course of action in this case?

Below is the flow we use today.
[image: This is the Flow we use today]

Forgot to mention, since we can't deploy versions all the time we are limited to the end of the day, that's why there would be no problem finishing the hotfix by the end of the day

Comment: The root cause of your problem seems to be having to do many hotfixes. You can do stuff to make them less painful, but it sounds like the real thing you need to do is release less buggy code to production.

Comment: Your diagram looks fairly standard to me. What exactly are the problems you're having with merging?

Comment: What problems are you having with merging? Why are you creating so many hotfixes? How often are you releasing? What do you mean by "as a manager, would finish the hotfix"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When done too much, *anything* can become overly cumbersome.

In this case, if you are doing multiple hotfixes a day, that's way too many. Hotfixes should be a last resort for things that are *pressing* (corrupted data, the inability to work with the software, just before a moment of important optics such as a demo or contract renewal, ...).

Just to get it out of the way, *how* you're doing your hotfixes is perfectly fine, i.e. merging the hotfix both to the master and develop branches.

Rather than simplify the hotfixing process, you should focus on minimizing the need for hotfixes. The main point against hotfixing (as opposed to a scheduled/planned patch release) is that **the time pressure related to a hotfix tends to detract from the quality of the fix**.

When under time pressure, developers are more likely to slap something together quickly to stop the proverbial burning hole in the production environment. When done repeatedly, this leads to your codebase getting shoddier as time goes by, which increases the likelihood of developers struggling to mantain full control over the codebase, bugs slipping through the cracks, and needing to hotfix even more.

You didn't really mention the focus of these hotfixes, so I can't give you a targeted approach. But in general, after (or during) hotfixing a bug, make sure to **identify what caused the bug in the first place**. Based on the cause, and how frequent this cause leads to needing a hotfix, adjust your development process accordingly:

- Was it a simple developer error and easy to spot?

  - Your test suite and/or code review process is likely not comprehensive enough.
- Was this just some bad code by an inexperienced developer, or a developer inexperienced with this specific tech stack?

  - Some mentoring/guidance would prevent similar mistakes in the future.
- Was this a very hard to spot issue because of complex logic?

  - The code should be refactored to reduce complexity.
- Was this a known flaw that was merged due to deadline/time constraint?

  - Favor delaying a feature for the next release if it is not ready yet, rather pushing out a flawed implementation. It costs more time to half-ass a feature, debug production code, and then full-ass the feature; as opposed to full-assing it from the get go.
- Did this bug irreversibly corrupt production data?

  - You should do more acceptance (QA) testing on a copy of live data to confirm the acceptance criteria are met.
- Is it performance-related?

  - If this happens frequently, consider investing some time in some in-depth tracing of bottlenecks and properly refactoring those (i.e. not just a quick fix for prod).

Note, however, that not every bug has a source that *should* have been avoided. There is some limit of control where it is no longer cost-effective to micromanage the code and wholly prevent mistakes.
For example, who says your test suite has correct tests? Who tests the test suite? This seems important, but it's actually way too much effort to test the test suite than it is to deal with the handful of issues that may slip through the cracks. This is more something that you bring to the attention of the dev team, and stress the importance of reviewing each other's code.

Where that limit lies is a matter of what your business requirements are and the severity of letting mistakes slip into production. From your question, I infer that mistakes in the production environment are not grievous, just a nuisance. Take this into account when doing the cost-benefit analysis on how much effort it costs to prevent an issue from arising vs dealing with issues as they arise.
To be clear, I'm not telling you to not do things properly. What I'm saying is that in more serious cases where production bugs could cause death or grievous bodily harm (e.g. medical appliances, safety installations, ...), there is a much higher limit on how much QA your product needs.

There's no real universal solution here. It's a matter of observing what mistakes are being made, and then figuring out a way to change the development process so that these mistakes are made less (or not at all anymore), without opening the door to other issues.

Comment: Thank you for your input!

I will use those points you pointed out to adapt the current flow we use, since there are limitations like we can't deploy a version until the end of the day, **unless extremely** urgent since the final customer would go down for about 5 minutes. 

The main problem seem to be our process, so we will be fixing that and then adapt the flow as we need.

Answer (score 1):

Hot fixes should be rare, if you are having so many that merging is difficult you have some serious lack of QA and/or you have a poor process. There are two big things that should help make things a bit easier.

1. Release MORE, your branches are more in sync, there is less time per release to even get a lot of hot fixes.
2. Restrict features flowing into dev more, get more testing on features before they are allowed into develop. The less good way is a blanket ban of PRs for X time, but it can keep develop clean for merging hot fixes.